# Source of "Vision is to touch with the gaze"

Tags: phenomenology

I have been going back through every note and flagged book I have and trying every search term combination to try to find the source of a quote or passage that noted the concept that 'vision is to touch with the gaze.' It may not be an exact quote but it was something almost verbatim that I think was either in Sartre or Merleau-Ponty... There are a lot of writings that touch on similar ideas but do not directly address the idea of vision as an extension of a kind of psuedo-tactile experience.
Any source would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Phenomenology of Perception, Merleau-Ponty says
that vision is not (merely) a passive process of receiving information from the world, but an active engagement with it.

> [The gaze] is a way of touching the world and it can caress or bruise, wound or heal.

Comment: yeah i was gonna mention that